# How to change env variable value after build

Tags: reactjs

I am a React beginner.
Develop with React, build and deploy to the server.
When deploying, use'yarn run build' to upload the resulting file to the server apache.
During development, the address of the API server was set in the .env file.
After building and deploying, I want to change the API server address in the .env file.
But there is no .env file in the built file...

It seems that the value of the .env file cannot be modified.
In this case, is there a way to change the setting value without build even after deployment?

Comment: What deployment tool are you using ? On Heroku, you can setup your environment variables in the `settings` tab of your project dashboard. On Zeit, you can use custom .env files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two env files .env.development and .env.production under root path and whatever you define in .env.development will work for local and whatever you define inside .env.production will work when you create build that is it is being switched to production mode

[image]

Comment: that does not explain how to change a .env variable after the build, just how to prepare the .env files for a possible production build.